# Add/Styling div for classes with GWT/HTML

Tags: java, jquery, html, css, gwt

I'm fairly new to GWT and I've been looking and trying everything for an answer but I still cannot find one.

My problem:
We are currently working on a function schedule system in GWT, and i'm trying to design the frontend. We currently have 4 classes (+a main class) for the 4 different "views" on the webpage. The schedule, navigator, bookmark sections and search. 
My question: Is there a way to have each of these classes (or widgets) inheret the position of a div class that i made in html/css.

The current html/css thats generated from GWT is:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Main.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="main/main.nocache.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- OPTIONAL: include this if you want history support -->
    <iframe src="javascript:''" id="__gwt_historyFrame" tabIndex='-1' style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0;border:0"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there a way that you can make GWT generate a div for each of the classes which you can nest into different css/html code that you've made?

For example:
Adding a navigator bar over the calender part.

Comment: How does this question involve programming with Java? Why the Java tag for your question? Do you mean JavaScript perhaps? If so, you'll want to change the tag in order to attract the correct experts to the question.

Comment: GWT uses java. I assumed I would have to add/edit/delete something in the java code.

Answer (score 0):

Yea your views can very much inherit the div attributes... give your attributes an ID ie  those attributes which are going to inherit the positions of main page .

Comment: I tried this, but the widget would not move. But if i typed something into the HTML, it would have those attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I am developing with the GWT Framework and I don't think you can mix things up. GWT enables you to create all your view in Java (even the css style, even if it's cleaner to definie it (and possible) in a css style sheet). You should take a look this page: [GWT Project - Layouts](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels.html#LayoutPanels)

In a nut, your four classes should extend the class named Widget. Once you have done that, you can create (for instance), a DockLayoutPanel, which will be your main container. See below a quick example (from [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DockLayoutPanel.html)):

```
public class DockLayoutPanelExample implements EntryPoint {

 public void onModuleLoad() {
        // Attach five widgets to a DockLayoutPanel, one in each direction. Lay
        // them out in 'em' units.
        DockLayoutPanel p = new DockLayoutPanel(Unit.EM);
        p.addNorth(new HTML("north"), 2);
        p.addSouth(new HTML("south"), 2);
        p.addEast(new HTML("east"), 2);
        p.addWest(new HTML("west"), 2);
        p.add(new HTML("center"));

        // Attach the LayoutPanel to the RootLayoutPanel. The latter will listen for
        // resize events on the window to ensure that its children are informed of
        // possible size changes.
        RootLayoutPanel rp = RootLayoutPanel.get();
        rp.add(p);
      }
    }
```

Here they add HTML objects (which equivalent in html is basically div) to the layout. Instead of adding HTML objects, add your four objects extending Widget.

In GWT, each Java object has an equivalent in HTML or Javascript and this conversion is done during the compilation.